# incompatible return type using multiple classes

Tags: java

Im writing a program to simulate simple queues of Process Control Blocks and having an issue with a return value in my returnPcb() method. I am getting an "invalid return type".  I know the return type in my method is a Pcb, but I cannot change it.  I want to return the value of -1 if the the call to removePcb() is false.  My thought was to create a new Pcb, set a value to -1, and return that value.  This is where I am running into issues.  I need help returning -1 when the condition is false. Thank you.

MasterQueue Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MasterQueue {

    HashMap<String,Queue<Pcb>>hash;

    MasterQueue(){
        hash = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public boolean addQueue(String nameIn){
        String QueueName = nameIn;
        if(hash.containsKey(QueueName)){
            return false;
        }
        //else add new queue the hashmap
        else{
            Queue<Pcb> q = new LinkedList<>();
            hash.put(QueueName,q);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean addPcb(Pcb p,String nameIn){
        String PcbName = nameIn;
        //if queue exist in the list then add the pcb to it
        if(hash.containsKey(PcbName)){
            hash.get(PcbName).add(p);
            return true;
        }
        //else return false
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Pcb removePcb(String nameIn){
        String RemovePcbName = nameIn;
        //if this queue exist in the list then remove first element from the queue
        if(hash.containsKey(RemovePcbName)){
            return hash.get(RemovePcbName).remove();
        }
        Pcb p = new Pcb(0, 0, 0, -1);
        return p.getPid();
    }

}
```

PCB Class:

```
public class Pcb {


private int low;
private int high;
private int state;
int pid;

Pcb(int lowMemIn, int highMemIn, int stateIn, int pidIn){
    setLowMem(lowMemIn);
    setHighMem(highMemIn);
    setState(stateIn);
    setPid(pidIn);
}

public void setLowMem(int lowMemIn){
    low = lowMemIn;
}

public int getLowMem(){
    return low;
}

public void setHighMem(int highMemIn) {
    high = highMemIn;
}

public int getHighMem(){
    return high;
}

public void setState(int stateIn){
    state = stateIn;
}

public int getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setPid(int pidIn){
    pid = pidIn;
}

public int getPid(){
    return pid;
}
}
```

Test

```
@Test
public void testAddPcb1() {
    Pcb pid1 = new Pcb(1, 2, 3, 4);
    MasterQueue mq1 = new MasterQueue();
    mq1.addQueue("miniQueueStr");

    Assert.assertTrue("error", mq1.addPcb(pid1, "miniQueueStr"));
```

Comment: Where is this `returnPcb` in your code? Also, on a different note, if you declare `HashMap<String,Queue<Pcb>> hash;` then it's a good idea initialise it with those same generics, using `hash = new HashMap<String,Queue<Pcb>>();`

Answer (score 1):

Your method is currently defined as:

```
public Pcb removePcb(String nameIn){
    String RemovePcbName = nameIn;
    //if this queue exist in the list then remove first element from the queue
    if(hash.containsKey(RemovePcbName)){
        return hash.get(RemovePcbName).remove();
    }
    Pcb p = new Pcb(0, 0, 0, -1);
    return p.getPid();
}
```

so you promised the compiler that this code would be returning a `Pcb` object, and nothing else. You can't just decide to make it return something else instead, it *has* to be a Pcb object.

So do that: you define that failcase `Pcb p = Pcb(0,0,0,-1)` so just return that `p` at the end of the function and the compiler will be happy.

However, if there is no matching Pcb, you really shouldn't be returning a Pcb object that happens to be set to values that you assume have meaning without formally declaring it as some constant, at which point things get silly... What you probably want to do instead is make your function throw:

```
public Pcb removePcb(String nameIn) throws NoSuchElementException {
    String RemovePcbName = nameIn;
    //if this queue exist in the list then remove first element from the queue
    if(hash.containsKey(RemovePcbName)){
        return hash.get(RemovePcbName).remove();
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

And then in your consuming code, put that removal call inside a try/catch and do what you as programmer know needs to happen when someone tries to remove a Pcb that doesn't exist.

Comment: I cannot add exception handling.  I only want to return a -1 value.  If i return p, after creating my Pcb object, my test still fails.  I have added my test above.

Comment: What you want, and what you can do in Java, are not aligned, and you should be doing what java lets you do, not "what another language might let you do". Java is a strongly typed, compiled language, and you don't get to "return a number" if your method signature says it will return a "not a number" type. So it really is as simple as that: normal Java code would throw, here. As for your test: all it does it add, so how does that show the remove being a problem?